# fetch-mock mocking all requests

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mocking, fetch, fetch-mock

I'm using fetch-mock in order to mock some requests to the server. This is where all the requests are made:

```
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock'
import initialState from 'src/initial-state'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  fetchMock.post('/some/endpoint', initialState.entities.multichannelEngagement)
}
```

But not only this endpoint is being mock, but all the requests made with isomorphic-fetch

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
export function makeRequest(endpoint, config = {}) {
  return window.fetch(endpoint, config)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  .then(json => ({ json, response }))
  .catch(() => ({ response }))
})
.then(({ json, response }) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw json ? json : new Error(response.statusText)
  } else {
    return json
  }
})
.catch((e) => {
  return Promise.reject(e)
})
```

}

My webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
import path from 'path'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import info from './package.json'

const resolvePath = p => path.join(__dirname, p)

const __DEV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const { parsed: env } = dotenv.load()
env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV
Object.keys(env).forEach(k => env[k] = JSON.stringify(env[k]))

const config = {
  name: info.name,

  entry: {
    app: 'src/index',
    vendor: Object.keys(info.dependencies)
  },

  output: {
    path: __DEV__ ? resolvePath('public') : resolvePath('../analytics-server/server/public'),
    filename: '/js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    debug: __DEV__,
    pathinfo: __DEV__
  },

  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      // NOTE: Run linter before transpiling
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      // TODO: Remove after upgrading to webpack 2
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: resolvePath('src'),
      core: resolvePath('src/core'),
      components: resolvePath('src/components'),
      modules: resolvePath('src/modules'),
      services: resolvePath('src/services'),
      resources: resolvePath('src/resources'),
      locales: resolvePath('src/locales')
    },
    // NOTE: Empty string to properly resolve when providing extension
    // TODO: Remove after upgrading to webpack 2
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },

  plugins: [
    // NOTE: `NoErrorsPlugin` causes eslint warnings to stop the build   process
    // new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('commons', '/js/commons.js'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ process: { env } })
// new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin( /^fetch-mock$/, path.resolve( __dirname, 'node_modules', 'fetch-mock/src/client.js' ) )
  ],

  eslint: {
    configFile: resolvePath('.eslintrc')
  }
}

if (__DEV__) {
  config.devtool = 'source-map'

  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: 'public',
    // NOTE: Options `inline` and `hot` shall be passed as CLI arguments
    // inline: true,
    // hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
} else {
  config.plugins.push(...[
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: true,
      acorn: true
    })
  ])
}

export default config
```

The error I get when I run the app is 
"fetch-mock.js:93 Uncaught Error: No fallback response defined for GET to http://localhost:3000/api/session"
which is the first request made in the app.

No idea why fetch-mock is mocking all requests. When evaluating on the chrome console, the value of the fetch on the makeRequest function is the fetch-mock function but as far as I know this is right.

BTW, I'm not in testing env, I'm on development because I need my backend mocked because it is not done yet.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused because `fetch-mock`'s main goal is to help with testing. In a test environment, it's better if you get an exception for any non-mocked calls being dispatched.

You can however add a `catch` handler that delegates to the original `fetch`, so any non-mocked request is passed to the real fetch. Something like the following:

```
/* FAKE FETCH ME */
  fetchMock.get('/session', function getSession(url, opts) {
    const jwt = extractToken(opts)
    if (!jwt || jwt !== fakeToken) {
      return delay({
        status: 401,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          details: 'Unauthorized'
        })
      })
    }
    return delay({
      status: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        success: true,
        data: fakeUserDetails
      })
    })
  })
  .catch(unmatchedUrl => {
    // fallover call original fetch, because fetch-mock treats
    // any unmatched call as an error - its target is testing
    return realFetch(unmatchedUrl)
  })
```

The library used to have an option for that but it was removed in V5. See documentation here:

> In previous versions fetch-mock had a greed property, set to
>
> - good - unmatched calls respond with a 200
> - bad - unmatched calls error
> - none - allow unmatched calls to use native fetch and the network
>
> This has now been replaced by a .catch() method which accepts the same
>   types of response as a normal call to .mock(matcher, response). It can
>   also take an arbitrary function to completely customise behaviour of
>   unmatched calls. It is chainable and can be called before or after
>   other calls to .mock(). The api to check for unmatched calls remains
>   unchanged.

https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/blob/master/V4_V5_UPGRADE_NOTES.md#handling-unmatched-calls-greed

Comment: Thanks dude, that's it

Answer (score 2):

Since fetch-mock v.6.5 there is a new config property called `fallbackToNetwork` that allows you to control how unhandled (unmatched) calls shall be handled by `fetch-mock`

http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#usageconfiguration